# Is there an equivalent of mallopt() in Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, memory-management, malloc

Linux offers customization options for memory allocation via `mallopt()`. Are there similar options for customizing memory allocation on OS X (BSD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X used to include the `mallopt()` function, although now it releases memory differently than in the past, so you'll need to find an alternative in versions 10.7 and above. It's unclear what type of specific `mallopt()` memory allocation options you're looking for, although most of the equivalent functions would be found in the following headers:

```
/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h
/usr/include/mach/vm_map.h
```

Functions that you might find similar in functionality to `mallopts()`:

**malloc_zone_pressure_relief()**

> advises the malloc subsystem that the process is under memory pressure
>   and that the subsystem should make its best effort towards releasing
>   (i.e. munmap()-ing) "goal" bytes from "zone". If "goal" is passed as
>   zero, the malloc subsystem will attempt to achieve maximal pressure
>   relief in "zone". If "zone" is passed as NULL, all zones are examined
>   for pressure relief opportunities. malloc_zone_pressure_relief()
>   returns the number of bytes released.

**vm_allocate()**

> allocates a region of virtual memory in the specified task's address
>   space.  A new region is always zero filled.

↳ [OS X Memory Usage Performance Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html)